# Implementation of Nginx Container for Reverse Proxying and SSL certificates for Django Containers inside Docker Swarm

Tags: django, docker, nginx, ssl, docker-swarm

I want to deploy Django Application with Docker Swarm.
I was following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-and-secure-a-django-application-with-docker-nginx-and-let-s-encrypt) where it does not use the docker swarm nor docker-compose, and specifically created two Django containers, one Nginx container, and a Certbot container for the SSL certificate.
The Nginx container reverse proxy and load balance across the two Django containers which are in the two servers using their IPs

```
upstream django {
    server APP_SERVER_1_IP;
    server APP_SERVER_2_IP;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name your_domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name your_domain.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://django;
        }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }



}
```

I want to implement all this same functionality but with Docker Swarm so that I can scale the containers with one command `docker service update --replicas 3 <servicename>`

The problem is I am not able to understand How to use implement the Nginx container in this scenario, Docker Swarm provides its load balancing so I did not need Nginx for that but Nginx is still needed for SSL certificates. So how do I implement Nginx in Swarm so it would provide SSL certificates for all nodes and reverse proxy to Django containers?
I only used Nginx before for reverse proxying so I am not able to figure how to write the Nginx conf and make the Nginx Container work with the Django Container with SSL included all inside a Docker Swarm.

```
####################
# docker-stack.yml #
####################
version: '3.7'
services:
    web:
      image: 127.0.0.1:5000/django-image
      deploy:
        replicas: 3
      command: gunicorn mydjangoapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
      expose:
        - 8000
      depends_on:
        - nginx
    nginx:
      image: 127.0.0.1:5000/nginx-image
      deploy:
        replicas: 2
      ports:
        - 80:80
      depends_on:
        - web
```

nginx.conf that I used for compose-file for pointing towards one Django Container

```
upstream django {
    server web:8000; #web is name of django service
}

server {
    #SSL STUFF        
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, between nginx and the world you can choose to let dockers ingress loadbalance to your nginx instances, or use an external loadbalancer. If you had a fixed set of nodes that an external loadbalancer was pointing to then

```yaml
 nginx:
   image: 127.0.0.1:5000/nginx-image
   ports:
   - 443:443
   networks:
   - proxy
   deploy:
     mode: global
     placement:
       constraints:
       - node.labels.myorg.lb==true
```

and label the corresponding nodes with `myorg.lb=true`

Next, as to your service, docker basically has 2 ways of advertizing replicated services: vip and dnsrr. With `vip` mode - the default - docker will assign a single ip address to the name "web" - which is what you give to the nginx replicas, and then it will loadbalance traffic between that. You can switch a service to dnsrr mode, in which case dns queries on web will be a dynamic changing list of the current ips of all the service replicas. Alternatively, you can use the explicit name `tasks.<service>` to get the same dnsrr entry.

Now. I dont know if nginx supports loadbalancing to dnsrr out the box. but I do know that it caches entries for a long time and so you will want to setup nginx with an explicit resolver (127.0.0.11) with a short refresh interval.

```yaml
  web:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/django-image
    command: gunicorn mydjangoapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    networks:
    - proxy
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Chris Becke for your help. So setting dnsrr as endpoint mode would act as one IP pointing towards all the container replicas deployed in that service meaning in Nginx.conf I would have to write it to point to the service name, i.e., web:8000. Right? If I'm wrong Please add the Nginx.conf file in case you can. It'll be of great help.